# Codeigniter picture resizing not fully working

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I'm making a website on CodeIgniter so users can add products to my website. I made a resize function so the picture would also create a thumbnail.
Now, this thumbnail only gets resized if the picture is bigger than width: 168 px and height: 112px . If the picture is smaller than that, the picture doesn't get resized. I want all pictures I upload to have a thumbnail picture that is 168px width and 112px height.

thumbnail image code:

```
 $dataThumb = $this->upload->data();
        $configThumb['image_library'] = 'gd2';
        $configThumb['source_image'] = './upload/'.$dataThumb["raw_name"].$dataThumb['file_ext'];
        $configThumb['new_image'] = './upload/'.'thumb_'.$dataThumb["raw_name"].$dataThumb['file_ext'];
        $configThumb['create_thumb'] = TRUE;
        $configThumb['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
        $configThumb['width'] = 168;
        $configThumb['height'] = 112;
```

My full upload product code:

```
public function upload() {
        $this->load->library('upload');
        $this->load->library('image_lib');

        $config['upload_path'] = './upload/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|bmp|jpeg';
        $config['max_size']    = '0';
        $config['max_width']  = '0';
        $config['max_height']  = '0';
        $config['encrypt_name']= true;
        $this->upload->initialize($config);


        if(!$this->upload->do_upload('userfile')){
            $error = array('error'=>$this->upload->display_errors());
            $this->load->view('product_form', $error);
        }else{
           //Main image
            $data = $this->upload->data();
            $config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
            $config['source_image'] = './upload/'.$data["raw_name"].$data['file_ext'];
            $config['new_image'] = './upload/'.'new_'.$data["raw_name"].$data['file_ext'];
            $config['create_thumb'] = FALSE;
            $config['maintain_ratio'] = FALSE;
            $config['width'] = 547;
            $config['height'] = 430;

            //Thumb image
            $dataThumb = $this->upload->data();
            $configThumb['image_library'] = 'gd2';
            $configThumb['source_image'] = './upload/'.$dataThumb["raw_name"].$dataThumb['file_ext'];
            $configThumb['new_image'] = './upload/'.'thumb_'.$dataThumb["raw_name"].$dataThumb['file_ext'];
            $configThumb['create_thumb'] = TRUE;
            $configThumb['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
            $configThumb['width'] = 168;
            $configThumb['height'] = 112;

            $this->image_lib->initialize($config);
            $this->image_lib->resize();

            $this->image_lib->initialize($configThumb);
            $this->image_lib->resize();

            $this-> db-> insert('products', array(
                'user_id' => $_SESSION['user_id'],
                'product_foto' => 'new_'.$data["raw_name"].$data['file_ext'],
                'product_foto_thumb' => 'thumb_'.$dataThumb["raw_name"].$dataThumb['file_ext'],
                'product_naam' => $this->input->post('product_naam'),
                'product_beschrijving' => $this->input->post('product_beschrijving'),
                'ophaal_plaats' => $this->input->post('ophaal_plaats'),
                'category_id' => !empty($this->input->post('category_id')) ? $this->input->post('category_id') : 0,
                'date_created' => date('Y-m-d'),
                'date_updated' => date('Y-m-d')
                ));
            $data['img'] = base_url().
            '/upload/new_'.$data["raw_name"].$data['file_ext'];
            $dataThumb['img'] = base_url().
            '/upload/thumb_'.$dataThumb["raw_name"].$dataThumb['file_ext'];

            header('location:https://kadokado-ferran10.c9users.io/Product/');

        }
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: The problem is that the smaller pictures I upload are not getting resized to 168 width and 112 height

Comment: Do you have debugging set up so you could watch it wend it's way through `system/libraries/Image_lib.php` and see what that final $width and $height are set to? (Or insert a bunch of `log_message` commands at points of interest.)

Comment: Also this from [the documentation](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/image_lib.html#CI_Image_lib::resize): `For practical purposes there is no difference between creating a copy and creating a thumbnail except a thumb will have the thumbnail marker as part of the name (i.e. mypic_thumb.jpg).` Maybe toss the thumb option and rename it yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
```

The above code Specifies whether to maintain the original aspect ratio when resizing. If it set to true it will change your image resolution.

```
$config['maintain_ratio'] = FALSE; //DO this
```

This will keep your resolution fixed.
I tested this and it worked.
Below is result:
Original image was both 512 X 512 (Larger than your dimension) and 100 X 100 (Smaller than your dimension)
[image]

Comment: I did at my thumbnail picture, just look at my code

Comment: So exactly what's your problem can you elaborate more

Comment: As you can see at my thumbnail picture code i set this picture size: $configThumb['width'] = 168;
            $configThumb['height'] = 112  . Ok so I want all pictures to resize to that picture size even if a picture is smaller than that size. So now only when a picture is bigger than that size it gets resized but if its smaller than that size it doesn't. Do you understand what I mean?

Comment: After your comment I just changed my answer refer that and that will 100% works for you. also read the manual here>> https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/image_lib.html

Comment: I'm sorry but I have less than 15 reputation so I am not able to upvote it